Unity: Script Not Found in Android Build Despite Working in Editor
I have a waypoint script, which is attached to a game object.
When i try to find the script using findobjectoftype method in unity editor it works fine, and it finds that script. But in android build it can't find the script.After building the game, When i check the editor log, it says "Waypoint" source file could not be found. What should i do to make this work?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I finally found that the gameobject has an EditorOnly flag set. I don't know how it was set to EditorOnly. After i changed the tag, it works as expected. It took me two days and 24 mobile builds to find this.
